# own \maketitle with multiple authors

Tags: pdftex, errors, compiling, compilation-error

I would like to create a latex template and define "\makefile" myself. Everything works until I define several authors with "\and". How can I change this?

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{center}
    \@date \hfill \theuni
    \smallskip
    \hrule
    \bigskip
    {\LARGE \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}}\\
    \smallskip
    {\large \thelecture\ - \@date}\\
    \bigskip
    {\Large \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\thegroup}}}\\
    \smallskip
    \@author

\end{center}
\hrule}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile. How is `\@author` defined? Or `\thelecture` or `\thegroup`? In what sense doesn't it work? If you get an error, which one? If you're using the definition of `\@author` and `\and` from one of the standard classes, they expect to be used in a `tabular`. Or, rather, `\and` expects to be inside one set up by `\\maketitle`.

Comment: I'd recommend using the `titling` package. It makes it easy to customise your title and you could configure the design you seem to have in mind very simply. Of course, sans code, it's impossible to say this with much confidence.

Comment: The easy solution is `\author{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal fix based on a guess as to what you're doing. Note that `\thexyz` is standardly used to typeset the value of counter `xyz`, so is best avoided in other cases. Assuming this convention, I get numbers for university, lecture and group. If they're not meant to be numbers, it would be better to use some other method to name the commands e.g `\jonathan@uni` or `\my@group` or `\custom@lecture`.

Assuming you had somehow defined those commands and so weren't asking about the errors I got trying to compile your snippet, I'm assuming the error concerned a `tabular` or `array`. Again, assuming you're using the definition of `\@author` and `\and` from one of the standard classes, these are designed to be used in the context of a `tabular` environment created by `\maketitle`. In particular each `\and` tries to end that environment and start another, so in your definition, you get `\end{tabular}` with no preceding `\begin{tabular}`. The simplest way to fix this is to supply a suitable environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\makeatletter
% note that \thexyz is used for counter xyz
\newcounter{uni}
\newcounter{group}
\newcounter{lecture}
\setcounter{uni}{1}
\setcounter{group}{34}
\setcounter{lecture}{789}
\RenewDocumentCommand \thegroup {} {Group \Roman{group}}
\RenewDocumentCommand \theuni {} {University \textnumero \arabic{uni}}
\RenewDocumentCommand \thelecture {} {Lecture \arabic{lecture}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\maketitle}{}{%
\begin{center}
  \@date \hfill \theuni
  \smallskip
  \hrule
  \bigskip
  {\LARGE \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}\par}
  \smallskip
  {\large \thelecture\ - \@date\par}
  \bigskip
  {\Large \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\thegroup}}\par}
  \smallskip
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \@author
  \end{tabular}
  
\end{center}
\hrule}
\makeatother
\author{Sandy \and Alex \and Sam \and Chris}
\title{What is the Title of this Article?}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: custom title with tabulated authors]

I'd recommend use of the `titling` package which will take care of these things for you and provides a comprehensive set of hooks for customisation.